# How to use double quotations in a URL in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, url-encoding

I want to use double quotations in the URL of my VB software, tried nearly everything but nothing works. Any suggestions?

For example, I want my program to search on for "Powered by BlogEngine.NET" but instead it searches without quotations like Powered by BlogEngine.NET

```
    Dork = " ""Powered by BlogEngine.NET"""
    Searchterm = FlatTextBox1.Text
    Input = FlatTextBox1.Text
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.google.com/search?q=" + Dork + " " + Searchterm + " " + TLD + "&tbs=qdr:" + UDate + "&num=" + Numbers)
```

Comment: May we see your code? If you are calling a URL with a query string, you probably need to urlencode your parameters.

Comment: OK, thanks for the update. Would you remove the backslash from your title? I don't think you intended to add that.

Comment: The code to do what you want can probably [be found here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vb.net+urlencode+string).

Comment: It should work if you change the line to Dork = " &quot;Powered by BlogEngine.NET&quot;"

Comment: `""` only escapes double quotes within VB strings, not in URLs. `&quot;` will not work either, that is HTML encoding, not URL encoding. All you need to do is replace the double quotes with `%22`, which equates to an escaped double quote...paste this in your web browser to see it work: `https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Powered by BlogEngine.NET%22`

Comment: soohoonigan Thanks Buddy it worked like a charm <3

Answer (score 0):

I see you have this working now but a better approach (also mentioned by @halfer) would be to build the url string then use [HttpUtility.URLEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t(v=vs.110).aspx) to properly convert the quotes and any other characters.